# Transforming from one CRS to another in Java

Tags: coordinate-system, java

I'm trying to have some code that is able to convert a 3D point from one CRS to another using Java. I want to be able to convert data from a compound CRS to another: for instance, a source CRS based on EPSG:25830 and ellipsoidal height to a CRS based on EPSG:4326 for horizontal and EPSG:5714 for vertical.

When I do this in python with pyproj, it seems to work fine:

```
from pyproj.crs import CompoundCRS, GeographicCRS, ProjectedCRS, VerticalCRS
target = CompoundCRS(
    name="target", components=[ CRS("EPSG:4326"), CRS("EPSG:5714")]
)

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(
    CRS("EPSG:25830").to_3d(),
    target,
    always_xy=True)

transformer.transform(428_999.93,  4_178_999.93, 1026.02) //(-3.8060066646351864, 37.75555714298539, 1026.02)
```

However, I'm struggling to find a nice way to do something like this from Java. I have tried different libraries (Apache SIS, Geotools, proj4j, proj4 JNI bindings) and the lat-long part seems to be resolved but I find errors on the altitude part.

For instance, with Apache SIS, I can do a transformation using the ellipsoidal as the vertical CRS for both source and target:

```
  CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.compound(CRS.forCode("EPSG:25830"), CommonCRS.Vertical.ELLIPSOIDAL.crs());

  CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.compound(CRS.forCode("EPSG:4326"), CommonCRS.Vertical.ELLIPSOIDAL.crs());

  CoordinateOperation operation = CRS.findOperation(sourceCRS, targetCRS, null);

  DirectPosition ptSrc = new GeneralDirectPosition(428_999.93, 4_178_999.93, 1026.02);
  DirectPosition ptDst = operation.getMathTransform().transform(ptSrc, null);
  System.out.println("Source: " + ptSrc);
  System.out.println("Target: " + ptDst);
  //Prints
  //Source: POINT(428999.93 4178999.93 1026.02)
  //Target: POINT(37.75555714201437 -3.806006664635183 1026.019960790058)
```

But if I replace the target vertical CRS for EPSG 5714

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.compound(CRS.forCode("EPSG:25830"), CommonCRS.Vertical.ELLIPSOIDAL.crs());  
  
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.compound(CRS.forCode("EPSG:4326"), CommonCRS.Vertical.ELLIPSOIDAL.crs());  
  
CoordinateOperation operation = CRS.findOperation(sourceCRS, targetCRS, null);  
  
DirectPosition ptSrc = new GeneralDirectPosition(428_999.93, 4_178_999.93, 1026.02);  
DirectPosition ptDst = operation.getMathTransform().transform(ptSrc, null);  
System.out.println("Source: " + ptSrc);  
System.out.println("Target: " + ptDst);
```

Then it throws:
Exception in thread "main" org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: Coordinate operation from system “ProjectedCRS[“ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N +…”]” to “CompoundCRS[“WGS 84 + MSL height”]” has not been found.

I'm not sure if it is a lack of my own understanding of CRS or about how I should be using the APIs exposed by these libraries, or simply a limitation of them.

Any idea on how I could get an output similar to the python code in Java and what libraries should I be using?